# How to keep track of the damage taken?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm making a simple 3D RPG game in Unity with a player and a bunch of enemies. What is the standard way to keep track of the damage taken in combat? I think the easiest way is to count damage everytime the attack animation is triggered, but how? How do I know whether an animation is triggered or not? Or is there any other way to do it? Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: I do onTriggerEnter on my damage. animation can miss the target therefore it will not count as damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to detect if the enemy hits you with a projectile/melee. The way to do that is attaching a collider to their weapon, you can do this by setting empty game objects as children of the weapon and attach individual collider components to them (**Don’t do this unless you know how to make it not take multiple damages at once. Just for extra precision**). Then what you want to do is for each/the collider hit the isTrigger check box so it has a check in it. Add a tag to the collider(s) that has a name like “damage” or “weapon”. Then open a script to attach to your player. Use `OnTriggerEnter()` to detect the weapon hitting your player:

```cs
...//the rest of your code before this.
public float health = 10f; //health value.
public float damageTick = 1f; //damage taken per hit
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider obj)
{
    //for same damage per different weapon hit.
    if (obj.GameObject.Tag == “damage”) //remember this is what the tag of the weapon was.
    {
        health -= damageTick;
        //play the animation. You can do that.
    }
    //*optional* for different damage per weapon type.
    if (obj.GameObject.Tag == “sword1”)
    {
         health -= sword1Damage; //make sure you have a variable for sword1Damage.
    }
    else if (obj.GameObject.Tag == “bow8”)
    {
         health -= bow8Damage; //make sure you have a variable for bow8Damage.
    }
    // add on to this if else, to make more weapons take different damage.

}
```

Comment: I wrote what I think you want after ‘//*optional*...’. If you saw that and are wondering how to do that, make sure you read the comments. You would have different variables containing the amount of damage you would take from different objects. Tag the different weapons(arrows for a bow; the actual thing that hits the player) with a different name for a different weapon. Use an if else to do different functions. For example: see line 13-20 in my post and there are examples.

Answer (score 1):

It's too expensive. If you have 10 enemies, then the calculations through the colliders will overload the system.
It's easier to calculate, when the user clicks on the attack button, create a primitive and see what objects are included in this primitive around it. Push them onto the stack. Further, if your attack is at a distance, you can count through the vectors of the nearest enemy, if the damage is massive, then you can set the hitting radius and inflict damage on all enemies in this zone using the observer pattern

Comment: Would you elaborate more, please? Thanks!